# Dividing area into a given number of squares

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry, packing

I have a DIV Element that can be resized by the user. Into this DIV I want to draw a given number of squares. Now I need to find out, what the perfect side length for the square would be so that all fit into the DIV without overflowing.

This is what I got so far:

```
function CalcSize (){
    var number = 23; // Example-Number
    var area = jQuery('#container').height() * jQuery('#container').width();
    var elementArea = parseInt(area / number);
    var sideLength = parseInt(Math.sqrt(elementArea));
    return sideLength;
}
```

This makes the squares too big since it does not "throw away" the space that cannot be filled with the squares. By searching for this problem I found the [Packing Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem) and Treemapping but both did not help me with my problem, since honestly I lack the math skills and from what I understand the solutions allow things like non-squares and rotations.

Thanks!

**Update:**

I currently use a very crude method to resize the squares by constantly resizing them and looking if they overflow. This method gives me the correct result but is quite bad on the performance. I am sure that this can be achieved by calculations.

[image: Link to a screenshot]

Comment: Are width and height of your parent div equal...?

Comment: No, the user can freely define the size of the DIV with the exception of a min-height/width and max-height/width controlled by CSS. The script will be fired when the user stopped resizing or when new elements get added or removed.

Comment: what exactly you mean by "does not throw away"? can you provide pictures please?

Comment: Then you cannot achieve squares ...

Comment: @Prasath: He can if he can leave part of the area unfilled.

Comment: also what do you mean by "perfect side length"? is it the largest length possible? You realize that it is not always possible, e.g. when number = 5, you won't be able to fill the rectangle with two rows of squares?

Comment: What if jQuery('#container').height() return a prime number like 997

Comment: Then the 'perfect' side length will be 1px?

Comment: I updated the post with a link to a screenshot. With "throw away" I meant that my currently not working solution does not seem to take into account that there is unfilled space. Regarding prime numbers: couldn't I take primes into account by reducing the number for the height/with by one in my calculations?

Comment: what you have there is actually pretty good. Imagine if we increased the size of the squares a little bit. Then the last column has to go away, and you would only have 4 columns in total. But there is no place where you can put those 4 squares, since you can not increase number of rows. Right?

Comment: Correct, that is why the current brute force method stopped right there. My hope was that I could find a solution that does not rely on loops to calculate the correct size.

Comment: I feel like you would still need a loop, although definitely better than brute-force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that will use the entire width and all unused space will be at the bottom. This will not always give the largest possible squares, but it will behave in a consistent manner and should look nice.

Note that the `while` loop should normally not go more than one or two iterations.

```
function CalcSize (){
    var number = 23; // Example-Number
    var width = jQuery('#container').width();
    var height = jQuery('#container').height();
    var area = height * width;
    var elementArea = parseInt(area / number);

    // Calculate side length if there is no "spill":
    var sideLength = parseInt(Math.sqrt(elementArea));

    // We now need to fit the squares. Let's reduce the square size 
    // so an integer number fits the width.
    var numX = ceil(width/sideLength);
    sideLength = width/numX;
    while (numX <= number) {
        // With a bit of luck, we are done.
        if (floor(height/sideLength) * numX >= number) {
            // They all fit! We are done!
            return sideLength;
        }
        // They don't fit. Make room for one more square i each row.
        numX++;
        sideLength = width/numX;
    }
    // Still doesn't fit? The window must be very wide
    // and low.
    sideLength = height;
    return sideLength;
}
```

Comment: Works very nicely! The unused space at the bottom actually fits my (in the question not explicitly stated) use case where elements get added in the runtime quite nice. Thanks a lot to everyone helping me with this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image, I made an assumption that you are ok with both vertical and horizontal unused spaces, as long as the length is maximized.

Basically this is a Linear Programming problem (well actually it is Integer Programming Problem). We have following inequalities and we want to maximize length.

rows,cols, and length are unknowns; and n, width, and height are given:

```
rows >= 1
cols >= 1
rows*cols >= n
rows*length <= height
cols*length <= width
maximize length
```

From the last 3 equations you got the estimate right: length <= sqrt(height*width/n).
You would still need to loop over the possible range to get the integer values though. You can do that a lot faster with [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: I have to fiddle around with the idea. Klas' Answer is pretty close to what I want. It now comes down to what one wants. The answer above uses not a lot of loop runs and it - visually - fits the squares to the width. I go with that now, but your answer comes close to my currently used method. Thank you a lot for your feedback!